# remove white space using strip()

Tags: python, scrapy

how can i remove the `[u'\n\n\n result here \n\n\n']`
and get have a result as `[u'result here']` only... I am using scrapy

```
def parse_items(self, response):
  str = ""
  hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

  for titles in titles:
      item = CraigslistSampleItem()
      item ["job_id"] = (id.select('text()').extract() #ok
      items.append(item)
  return(items)
end
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: `u'\n\n\n result here \n\n\n'.strip()` should do it.

Comment: i tried it using this =
item ["job_id"] = (id.select('text()').extract().strip()
but it gave me an error

Comment: @chano What is `id` here and what's the error? (It's a bad idea to use `id` as a variable name, `id()` is a built-in function)

Comment: item ["job_id"] = (id.select('text()').extract().strip()
the above syntax resulted as "exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object ahs no attribute 'strip'

Comment: `item["job_id"] = [i.strip() for i in id.select('text()').extract()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
id.select('text()').extract()
```

returns a list of string containing your text. You should either iterate over that list to strip each item or use slicing e.g your_list[0].strip() to perform striping white spaces. Strip method is actually associated with string data types.

```
def parse_items(self, response):
  str = ""
  hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

  for titles in titles:
      item = CraigslistSampleItem()
      item ["job_id"] = id.select('text()').extract()[0].strip() #this should work if #there is some string data available. otherwise it will give an index out of range error.
      items.append(item)
  return(items)
end
```

Comment: another question...
I created a denier like
path_deny_base = [
    '.(login)',
    '.(intro)',
    '(candidate)',
    '(referral)',
    '(reminder)',
    #'(\/search)',
] which supposedly must deny pages with the aforementioned string
but still my scraper crawls pages like https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/19997/registered-nurse-prn/login

my rule is:
rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = path_deny_base, allow=('https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/'),restrict_xpaths=('*'))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

Comment: @chano, you should probably ask another question on StackOverflow for this rule's deny issue

Comment: sorry.. I'm just new to this site.. Thank you for reminding mew

Answer (score 5):

**Alternative to using Python's `.strip()`**

You can use XPath function `normalize-space()` around your XPath expression that selects "job_id":

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item ["job_id"] = title.select('normalize-space(.//td[@scope="row"])').extract()[0].strip()
        items.append(item)
    return(items)
```

**Note 1**: the XPath expression I use is based on https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchLocation=&searchCategory=&hashed=0

**Note 2 on the answer using `.strip()`**: with `id.select('text()').extract()[0].strip()` you get `u'result here'`, not a list.

That may very well be what you need, but if you want to keep the list, as you asked to *remove `[u'\n\n\n result here \n\n\n']` and get have a result as `[u'result here']`*, you can use something like this, using Python's `map()`:

```
item ["job_id"] = map(unicode.strip, id.select('text()').extract())
```

Comment: oh... I checked my csv file and I found out that there is still a \nresult here\n on it... why is it so?

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! Nothing gets me angry like scraping complicated and irregular web pages and I happened to fix my problem using a portion of your answer after searching for an hour or so.

Comment: you can also use just .get().strip() without [0]